# How to handle simultaneous reading and writing

Tags: php, file, audio, streaming, mp3

I have a server that grabs mp3 audio buffers from a source and writes it into a file via php. It truncates the beginning of the file so the file size never exceeds 2 MB. At the same time a client is streaming the mp3 by seeking to the end and reading if there is any new data. The problem is when the file get's truncated the position the client was reading at changes.

This is the client side that streams the audio:

```
$handle = fopen('cool.mp3', "r");
$err = fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);
while(file_exists($file_lock)){ // cool.mp3.lock means stream is still going
    $data = fread($handle, 1024);
    echo $data;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

I use this on the server to write data as I get it:

```
$data = "audio frames....";
clearstatcache();
$file = 'cool.mp3';
if(filesize($file) > 1024*200){ //2 MB
    ftruncatestart($file, 1024*25); //Trim Down By Deleting Front
}
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: the server might need to update another file that keeps track of offset, then client can deduce the correct position by examining the difference in offsets.

Comment: @Fabricator would this work with multiple clients?

Comment: I think so because each client can calculate the position it needs to seek independently.